# save association in pivot table in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a common many to many relationship, these are the models:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :related_professions
  has_many :professions, through: :related_professions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :related_professions
end

class RelatedProfession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :profession

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profession
end

class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :related_professions
  has_many :employees ,through: :related_professions
end
```

I also have a form for saving *Employees*. In this form I would like to render all the *Professions* in a multiple select for the user to choose as needed. I want that when the user submits the form, the IDs of all the selected professions be saved in the *RelatedProfession* pivot table (which just have three columns: id, employee_id, profession_id). This is the part of my form for the select:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :professions %>
  <%= form.fields_for :related_professions do |rp| %>
    <%= rp.collection_select :profession_id, Profession.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this is the part in my *EmployeeController* that allows the parameters:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, related_professions_attributes: [:id, profession_id: [:id]])
end
```

The first problem is that the form does not load the *Professions* if the *Employee* does not have any assigned. I had to manually add one to the DB and then it would populate the select.

Second problem is that when I try to update the *Employee* (and also the *RelatedProfession* pivot table) by selecting a different *Profession*, it won't work, and I get this error:

```
Related professions profession must exist
```

I know there must be something wrong in the *permit* parameters and form that is not building the select correctly.

I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no need nested attributes to created has_many through relations,
You can just pass it as array of ids.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :related_professions
      has_many :professions, through: :related_professions
    end

    class RelatedProfession < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :employee
      belongs_to :profession
    end

    class Profession < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :related_professions
      has_many :employees ,through: :related_professions
    end
```

In form also just select ids of `Professions`.

```
 <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :professions %>
        <%= rp.collection_select :profession_ids, Profession.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
    </div>
```

change strong params to allow `profession_ids` as array.

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, profession_ids: [])
end
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This solved the first problem where the select for the _Professions_ was not being populated, but when I try to save a new _Employee_ assigning one Profession, it does not store the data in the _RelatedProfessions_ pivot table. I am getting this error:

**Unpermitted parameter: :related_professions**

And these are the params:

`"employee"=>{"name"=>"Another", "related_professions"=>{"profession_ids"=>["", "2"]}`

Comment: @Holland Salazar updated answer, just remove nested form from view

Comment: Thank you very much! That works as expected! It was confusing for me all the things about nested attributes. Best regards.